# Merge pdf documents into a single page iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to combine multiple pdf pages into a single pdf page.
There are many examples of iText showing how to combine pdf pages into a single file, but i need all the pages to fit into a single page (shrinking their width and height along they way)

```
    String[] files = { MovieLinks1.RESULT, MovieHistory.RESULT };
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
PdfReader reader;
int n;
// loop over the documents you want to concatenate
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
    // loop over the pages in that document
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
// step 5
document.close();
```

EDIT:
tried this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606156/4314222) but it just merges pdf pages into 1 file, i need them to shrink into 1 single page

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no joy"? It creates a dreary newspaper instead? Converts your document into a folded hat? Prints out all black? Please [edit] your question to add that missing information.

Comment: Sorry, i meant it doesn't merge into a single page, but to a single file with multiple pages. i need to merge 4 pages from 4 different pdf files into 1 single pdf sheet which contains all 4 pages (which are all shrunk to 25% of their original size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you **don't** want to copy the pages as they are as individual pages of a new document (which is the most common *Merge pdf documents* use case) but **instead** want *all the pages to fit into a single page (shrinking their width and height along they way*, the [code source you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606156/4314222) alone does not what you need: The code there focuses on the common use case.

Your use case reminds more of a  n-up use case. Thus, you should have a look at the n-up iText samples. The most obvious one is the [NUpTool](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115) in which the focal code is this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest, int pow)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // reader for the src file
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // initializations
    Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(1);
    Rectangle newSize = (pow % 2) == 0 ?
        new Rectangle(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight()) :
        new Rectangle(pageSize.getHeight(), pageSize.getWidth());
    Rectangle unitSize = new Rectangle(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
        unitSize = new Rectangle(unitSize.getHeight() / 2, unitSize.getWidth());
    }
    int n = (int)Math.pow(2, pow);
    int r = (int)Math.pow(2, pow / 2);
    int c = n / r;
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(newSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
       = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(String.format(dest, n)));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    Rectangle currentSize;
    float offsetX, offsetY, factor;
    int total = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            document.newPage();
        }
        currentSize = reader.getPageSize(++i);
        factor = Math.min(
            unitSize.getWidth() / currentSize.getWidth(),
            unitSize.getHeight() / currentSize.getHeight());
        offsetX = unitSize.getWidth() * ((i % n) % c)
          + (unitSize.getWidth() - (currentSize.getWidth() * factor)) / 2f;
        offsetY = newSize.getHeight() - (unitSize.getHeight() * (((i % n) / c) + 1))
          + (unitSize.getHeight() - (currentSize.getHeight() * factor)) / 2f;
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.addTemplate(page, factor, 0, 0, factor, offsetX, offsetY);
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

*([NUpTool.java](https://github.com/itext/book/blob/master/src/part2/chapter06/NUpTool.java))*

This method arranges the pages of the PDF *src* in a document *dest* with *2<sup>`pow`</sup>* source pages on each target page.

---

**For your use case, therefore,** after combining the pages in a single file as you already do, you merely have to post-process that single file in the routine above using the smallest value for `pow` for which 2<sup>`pow`</sup> is not less than the original number of pages.

Comment: precisely what i needed. Thank you