# Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open pdf file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using below code while merging single PDF file.

link : https://codesjava.com/itext-merge-pdf-files-in-java

Some times only, I am facing below issue, How can i resolve please help me, I should be use live.
itextpdf.5.4.4 version

Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open pdf file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: While Hakan's answer is right, merging PDFs should really be done using `PdfCopy`, not plain `PdfWriter`, even the latter variant should not result in broken PDFs. Most likely, therefore, there is a detail you don't mention. Have you checked the console for error messages when you merged PDFs? Also, please share a broken result PDF for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the mistake of trying to merge PDF files using the PDFWriter class.
It is bad code and should not be used according to the creator of the iText library.

See this post how to properly merge PDF files.

[Merge pdf documents of different width using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604555/merge-pdf-documents-of-different-width-using-itext/25606156#25606156)

You should be using the PDFCOPY class to merge files.

Also, you cannot merge a 'single' PDF file like your first sentence states. The idea of merging is to combine multiple pages or files.