# How to merge 2 large pdf files in .Net Core without large memory utilization

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext, pdf-generation

When combining PDF files via code, every implementation I've seen, requires all files to be opened before being combined into one. This works just fine for small files, but with large enough files, we can exceed the resources available to an azure function, causing the function to restart.

I am wondering if there is a way to simply append one file to another from the outside, without having to open them. As an analogy, consider the this command that can be executed on a command line: "copy *.txt newfile.txt". It will take all files ending in .txt and create a new file that combines them all. If I understand correctly, I don't believe it requires loading the entire contents of any individual file into memory, as it is merely doing a file system copy, but joining the files where one file ends and the other begins. Is there a similar approach that can be taken with pdfs?

We've tried various merge implementations where you load the pages of each file into a for loop and add each page to a renderer, one by one. Obviously the memory usage is directly proportional to the size of the files in this approach.

Comment: Merging PDF files is much, much more than concatenation. So, the short answer is no. It is possible to imagine a system where large objects (e.g raster images) from the input files could be copied in a low level way into the output file at the appropriate moment, without going through memory. But I don't know of any PDF system which can do that.

Comment: As you used the [tag:itext] tag, I assume you use iText version 4.x or 5.x. In that case, have you tried to port the iText/Java solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606156/1729265)?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is possible using the incremental update feature, you can modify a PDF document without affecting its original content by appending just the changes at the end of the file.

Here is the [Incremental Updates](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=52) specification.

Also, here is an example of merging PDF files with incremental updates using GemBox.Pdf:
[Merge a large number of PDF files](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-merge-pdf/201#merge-many-files)

The main point is to use `PdfDocument.Save()` overload method that has no parameters and then `PdfDocument.Unload()` method. That way only one file will be loaded at any given time.

```cs
using (var document = new PdfDocument())
{
    document.Save("Merged Files.pdf");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (var source = PdfDocument.Load(file))
            document.Pages.Kids.AddClone(source.Pages);

        // Save the new pages.
        document.Save();

        // Clear previously parsed pages and thus free the memory.
        document.Unload();
    }
}
```

We can go even further with this and unload any parsed objects after X pages.

```cs
int counter = 0;
using (var destination = new PdfDocument())
{
    destination.Save("Merged Files.pdf");

    foreach (var file in files)
        using (var source = PdfDocument.Load(file))
            for (int index = 0, count = source.Pages.Count; index < count; counter++, index++)
            {
                destination.Pages.AddClone(source.Pages[index]);
                // Unload after 100 pages.
                if (counter % 100 == 0)
                {
                    destination.Save();
                    destination.Unload();
                    source.Unload();
                }
            }

    destination.Save();
}
```

Comment: In your example, iText will still load the documents and parse them into memory so it can do the necessary changes to the files.  In order to concat them. Yes the first file can pretty much be the same, and the changes can be concatted. But it still needs to parse the first file to know what the object numbers are, and what objects need to be overwritten (page tree, etc). All the files that will be concatted need to be parsed completely and changed, to be able to be concatted.

Comment: @SynerCoder each file will be parsed when calling `document.Pages.Kids.AddClone(source.Pages)`, that is true, but those parsed objects will be freed on `document.Unload()` call. Again, please read about Incremental Updates. Just as an example of the content's independency, note that without this feature, PDF files wouldn't be able to have multiple digital signatures.

Comment: Sure... and the question was: "I am wondering if there is a way to simply append one file to another from the outside, without having to open them."... Your codes opens and parses them, so you don't answer the question. "we can exceed the resources available to an azure function", if you have a single PDF of 2gb, you still run into issues with your code. The point being, "no, it is not possible" to do what the asker wants.

Comment: @SynerCoder if the OP has such files, I would first suggest he tries unloading after each individual file was merged. If that doesn't work, which I really doubt will be his case, then he can try counting pages instead of files. This will work because the library I'm using also supports lazy loading (the page is not parsed unless you explicitly request it or access it).

Comment: @SynerCoder I've changed the code so that unloading is done for each file, that way only one file will be loaded at any given time. But as mentioned before, we can go with this even further and unload any parsed objects after X pages.

Comment: You are missing the point, being: "You can't concat 2 or more PDF files without opening them." Another point: the question references iText, but you suggest GemBox.Pdf, of which the free version only supports 2 pages. 
So you don't answer the question, but you are answering a different question: "How to concat 2 or more pdf files in C# using a paid technology by using as little memory as possible.". To that question, great answer. But that was not the question that was being asked.

Comment: @SynerCoder the point that I'm trying to make is that you can control how much the file is "opened" (or better said, how much it is loaded in the memory). The context that OP has is that he's limited with resources. You're being pedantic about the exact words he's using, instead, I would encourage you to consider his use case and what he's trying to do. He has large PDF files, those files can be merged on Azure Functions but he needs to use the memory efficiently by utilizing incremental updates and lazy loading. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that iText also supports those features.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR:** Unfortunately, no.

---

**Long version:** Pdf is a fileformat that is structured as follows:

```
[File header]
PDF objects
[XRef Table]
[Trailer object]
[startxref offset]
```

The file header is a few simple bytes indicating that it is a PDF file, then some >128 bytes to indicate a binary file.
All PDF objects look like this:

```
1 0 obj
[object]
endobj
```

Where 1 is the object number. So object 2 would start as: `2 0 obj` etc.

The XRef table is a list of objects and their byte offset in the file.

Objects can reference other objects. For example, the trailer object is a dictionary that contains a reference to the root element. The root element contains a reference to the pages object. The pages object contains one or more (might be an array) references to page object(s).

So when reading the PDF file, you start at the end, read the startxref value. That points to the start of the xref table. That table tells you at what byte offset the objects are, starting at object `1 0 obj`.

So if you would concat 2 files together, when reading the file, you would read the startxref value. but the offset would be incorrect, because the offset is off by the length of the first file. Even when correcting for that. The entire xref table is off by the first file length. And even when correcting that, you can still only read the last PDF. To actually concat the pages, you need to edit all the object numbers (and the references in the file that use that object) to be `[last object number from file 1 + n]`. Then you need to overwrite the previous pages object to also include all the pages of the second file.

That is not the hardest, because you can just create a new PageTree object that will reference both pagetree object numbers. You do need to update/overwrite the Catalog object to reference the newly created pagetree as the new root of the tree.

Then you need to create a new xref table that uses all the objects from both files, list them in correct order and their byte offsets.

Comment: @KJ correct, but the header is not at issue here. My whole point was more to illustrate just even the basics of concatting 2 pdf files. which need a lot of work. Like my TLDR said.... unfortunally not possible in a simple way.